# Monad transformers: IO and state

Tags: haskell

This question is close to ground covered elsewhere, but I haven't found anything that addresses it specifically (at least not in a way that I'm able to understand).

I'd like to update state in a way that depends on various random choices. Because of the instance of the RandomSource typeclass that I'm using, all of these random choices live in the IO monad, as below:

```
main :: IO Int
main = do
         a <- pickRand [1..7]
         return a

         where pickRand lst = runRVar (choice lst) DevRandom
```

What I'd like to do is something like the following: store a state of type [Int], and if the randomly chosen list element a is greater than 3 , push it onto the state. Any tips?

Comment: Please read about `StateT` monad transformer,

Comment: I have, at least to the extent that I've been able to find good resources. And what I've read has told me how to things *related* to what I want, for example how to print from a state monad with lift $ print. But I haven't a solution to my specific problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.Random.RVar
import Data.Random.Source.DevRandom
import Data.Random.List

myFun :: StateT [Int] IO ()
myFun = do
  lst <- get
  r <- liftIO $ runRVar (randomElement lst) DevRandom
  put $ if r > 3 then (r:lst) else lst
  return ()


main :: IO ()
main = evalStateT myFun [1..10] >>= print
```