# Print to console and update Monad state in same function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I want to define a function that expects an `Int`, prints an error in the console depending on the number (**x**) and then updates the `State` with `Nothing`.

How can I join those commands in one function?

Here's what I got:

```
  type Env = [(Variable,Int)]
  newtype StateError a = StateError { runStateError :: Env -> Maybe (a, Env) }
  class Monad m => MonadError m where
    throw :: Monad m => a -> m a

  instance MonadError StateError where
    throw x = StateError (\s -> Nothing)
```

But I can't figure out how to perform the `IO` side-effect and **then** the State update in the same function definition

Comment: This is why monad transformers exist! (In this case, `StateT`.)

Comment: could you please give me an example @ReinHenrichs

Comment: If you want to do `IO`, your monad will have to mention it; e.g. `newtype StateErrorIO a = StateErrorIO { runStateErrorIO :: Env -> IO (Maybe (a, Env)) }`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Monad transformers: IO and state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339274/monad-transformers-io-and-state) . maybe a better dupe out there

Comment: Do you want to learn how to _write_ a monad transformer or how to _use_ a monad transformer to accomplish your goal?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I want to use it to accomplish my goal (write a throw function for my parser evaluator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**

A function in the state monad, such as `a -> State s b`, is a pure function (no IO) that happens to have an extra function argument `s` hidden though some handy plumbing.

You can't print to the console from the state monad.

**However, Yes!**

However! You can use a monad *transformer* to get both State and some underlying monad such as IO.

I'll provide an example using `transformers` instead of a custom monad and `mtl` as it appears you were using.  With `mtl` you can use classes like `MonadError` to leverage a `throw` that works well with other libraries that use the mtl classes.  On the other hand, if you are the end consumer of this transformer it is less important.

First we'll import the modules that give us MonadIO, StateT, MaybeT, and use newtype deriving so we don't have to type out the monad instance boilerplate:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
import qualified Control.Monad.Trans.State as S
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad.Trans
```

Just to be complete we'll spell out the types useful to your abstraction:

```
type Variable = String
type Env = [(Variable,Int)]
```

Now we can get to the interesting part - a Monad definition and functions for plumbing.   The monad stack is StateT MaybeT IO:

```
newtype StateError a = StateError { unStateError :: S.StateT Env (MaybeT IO) a }
    deriving (Monad, Applicative, Functor)
```

And we can run it by first unwrapping the newtype, then running the state, and finally the MaybeT:

```
run :: StateError a -> IO (Maybe (a, Env))
run = runMaybeT . flip S.runStateT [] . unStateError
```

Usually you'll write an army of functions that provide your monad abstraction.  For this question it's just "update the state" and "print to stdout":

```
modify :: (Env -> Env) -> StateError ()
modify = StateError . S.modify

emit :: Show a => a -> StateError ()
emit = StateError . liftIO . print . show
```

Armed with our Monad of Power, we can do fancy things like update state *and* emit IO messages *and* track failure or success:

```
updateAndPrint :: Variable -> Int -> StateError ()
updateAndPrint v i =
  do emit (v,i)
     modify ((v,i):)
```

Oh, and failure is pretty simple - just fail in our `MaybeT` monad:

```
throw :: a -> StateError b
throw _ = fail ""  -- same as 'MaybeT (pure Nothing)'
```

We can use this monad as expected:

```
> run $ updateAndPrint "var" 1
"(\"var\",1)"
Just (()             -- ^ return value of `updateAndPrint`
     ,[("var",1)])   -- ^ resulting state
```